# What is the best way to monkey patch the RegExp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, monkeypatching

What would be the best approach (performance) to monkey patch or extend the RegExp prototype or other native Object.

I would like to add 1 method, for example, capture:

```
Object.assign(RegExp.prototype, {
  capture() {
    // code
  }
})
```

vs

```
RegExp.prototype.capture = () => {}
```

Is there a design pattern to do that?

Please, don't comment saying that this is a bad thing and could cause several problems. I'm just curious about it.

Comment: What issue are you having with the code at the Question?

Comment: I'm just curious about the best way to do it.

Comment: There is no "best" way

Comment: there is always a best way.

Comment: Then what is your decision as to which of the two code approaches at the Question is the "best way" to achieve requirement, and why?

Answer (score 0):

The two cases are mostly similar, create a new method in the prototype of RegExp. As it is a one time operation there is no noticeable performance difference between them.

Object.assign(...) is using the new ES6 and can add more than one method to the prototype.
RegExp.prototype.method = ... is the plain JavaScript mode.

Edit:
It depends on the syntax you like the most.